# Firebase count num children of parent

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get the number of children for a parent node in js firebase.
I'd like to have:

```
'user': {
    '-Yuna99s993m': { count: 1},
    '-Yada99s993m': { count: 2},
}
```

I'm creating a cloud function witch every time a new node is entered it should add count equal to numChildren of user node.

```
exports.setCount = functions.database.ref('/user/{userId}').onWrite(event => {
    // This doesn't work
    const count = event.data.ref.parent.numChildren();
    return event.data.ref.update({ count });
});
```

Any help to get this working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling `event.data.ref.parent.numChildren()` won't work, because `parent` is a `DatabaseReference` while `numChildren()` is defined on `DataSnapshot` (which you get by attaching a listener to a reference):

```
exports.setCount = functions.database.ref('/user/{userId}').onWrite(event => {
    return event.data.ref.parent.once("value", (snapshot) => {
      const count = snapshot.numChildren();
      return event.data.ref.update({ count });
    });
})
```

There is also a [`child-count` example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count) in the functions-samples Github repo that does precisely what you want: keeping a counter of the number of children. That example uses a more efficient approach for keeping the count.