# Most efficient way to count children with Firebase Database

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Currently i am doing it like this:

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Leaders").Child("List1");
         reference.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
         {
             int totalChildren = (int)task.Result.ChildrenCount;
               //Do more stuff
         }
```

I thought, why get whole Snapshot to count how many children.

Any different way without fetching whole Snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase does not have a built-in count operator. So you'll either have to download all child nodes to count them (as you're doing now), or keep a separate property where you track the number of child nodes.

The latter takes more work when writing, but leads to much simpler read performance. You'll find that this read-vs-write performance is a common trade-off in NoSQL databases.

For more on this, see:

- [In Firebase, is there a way to get the number of children of a node without loading all the node data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load)
- [Firebase count num children of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760645/firebase-count-num-children-of-parent)
- [How to get size of an element/list in Firebase without get it all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443421/how-to-get-size-of-an-element-list-in-firebase-without-get-it-all)

Comment: Thanks, so much limits the more you get into it.I can't save locally the number of children as it is a leaderboard and can be updated from different users. Hope they add that count option.

Comment: It is extremely unlike that a count option will be added to the Firebase Realtime Database at this point. But note that plenty of developers before you were able to show a count based on what I've shown above. All these approaches work across multiple users.

Comment: Yeah, your links are a good sum up of different solutions! I liked the 'shallow=true' , can't find any document explaining of it can be used via Unity Firebase SDK, as it seems only to work with Rest calls.

Comment: That is correct, shallow loading is only in the REST API. Keeping a counter in the database is by far the best approach.